# API returning empty array instead of data in Laravel Vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am doing a Laravel Vue project for school and i am supposed to get a user by sending its email from the client, but when the server responds i get an empty array from the response data instead of the data i want from the database.

Login.vue

```
login() {

        this.showMessage = true;
        this.typeofmsg = "alert";
        this.message = "Loggin in...";

        axios.post('api/login', this.user)
            .then(response => {
                const token = response.data.access_token;
                this.$store.commit('setAccessToken', token);
                return axios.get('api/users/me', this.user.email);
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("Error = " + error.message);
            });

    },
```

routes/api.js

```
Route::get('users/me', 'UserControllerAPI@myProfile');
```

UserControllerAPI

```
public function myProfile(Request $request){
    $email = $request->email;
    $user = User::where('email', $email)->first();
    return new UserResource($user);
}
```

If i try to get it with postman it works
[image]

And in the dev tools console i get this

[image]

Sorry if i wasn't clear enought or it is something wrongly made, i have been trying to fix this since yesterday and its driving me crazy. Any help appreciated

Edit: Had the route wrong, but i changed it and i get the same, no data. I changed the console picture too

Comment: From the dev tools console, it seems like the request is being changed to `/wallet` ... Unless that log is not of the request you just sent...

Comment: Hadn't notice that until now, i have a computed function that gets the total number of wallets for display, but i dont think that is related?

Comment: I've updated my answer, pls try it and see if it fixes the issue...

Comment: I tried to change some things and i am no longer gettin an html page, but i still cant access the data i am trying to get because it responds with an empty array. Already edited the post and added the new console log

Comment: I tried to change some things and i am no longer gettin an html page, but i still cant access the data i am trying to get because it responds with an empty array. Already edited the post and added the new console log

Comment: If you've updated your code, could u please update the post...?

Comment: The code is exactly the same, just relaunched my vagrant machine

Comment: Pls try my updated answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
return axios.get('api/users/me', this.user.email);
```

to

```
return axios.get('api/users/me', { params: { email: this.user.email } });
```

Comment: Yea i changed it but i still get the same, no usefull data. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Sorry, didnt see it until now. I changed that and i received the user data. Thank you very much for helping me

Comment: You're welcome... because the email wasn't getting sent... that resulted in a error 500 and the HTML you saw was the error 500 page being returned as the data...

Comment: Oh since i didnt had anything in the logs and i received the email in the server i believed it was getting send. Thank you for the explanation

Comment: To future proof the code, you could try adding exception handling in your controller so that it can properly send an error message with the correct status code if anything fails...

Answer (score 0):

You have api/user/me  and in route you have /userS/me

so I guess you have to either remove S or add S in one of the places.

so try to change in route

```
Route::get('users/me', 'UserControllerAPI@myProfile');
```

to

```
Route::get('/user/me', 'UserControllerAPI@myProfile');
```

Comment: yes, prior answer was right one, i didn't mention that axios param also was wrongly passed.